# Problem with updating a script for the sheets v4 API version

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am trying to update this script for the Sheets v4 API version but I am not successful...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON(
        //"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1iebtJB4FxhDVztxydXT85SNpgQNhOgJEp_F1qpTSkMI/od6/public/values?alt=json",
        "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1nt-5-zruTuJPOAfRbCgy9sJA2CCVvzo0sCPEPx0uxEk/values/Section-A/?alt=json&key=AIzaSyCJuQ_bsRn1SVyfI8rkeq0RUnSpecP7IYk",
        function(data) {

            var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

                var perc = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$changepct']['$t'];
                var cap = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$marketcap']['$t'];
                var date = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$tradetime']['$t'];
                var price = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$price']['$t'];

                document.getElementById('perc').innerHTML += (perc);
                document.getElementById('capitalizzazione').innerHTML += (cap);
                document.getElementById('dataTrade').innerHTML += (date);
                document.getElementById('price').innerHTML += (price);
            }
        });
}, 1000);
```

})

Could I have some help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The URL of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/###/od6/public/values?alt=json` is for Sheets API v3. When the Sheets API v4 is used, an API key is required to be used like `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`.

But, fortunately, when I saw your Spreadsheet, it seems that the Spreadsheet is published as the Web publish. I thought that in your situation, this might be used without using the API key. In this answer, I would like to propose this method. In this method, the values can be retrieved by the query language. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
jQuery.getJSON(
    //"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1iebtJB4FxhDVztxydXT85SNpgQNhOgJEp_F1qpTSkMI/od6/public/values?alt=json",
    "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1nt-5-zruTuJPOAfRbCgy9sJA2CCVvzo0sCPEPx0uxEk/values/Section-A/?alt=json&key=AIzaSyCJuQ_bsRn1SVyfI8rkeq0RUnSpecP7IYk",
    function(data) {

        var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

            var perc = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$changepct']['$t'];
            var cap = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$marketcap']['$t'];
            var date = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$tradetime']['$t'];
            var price = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$price']['$t'];

            document.getElementById('perc').innerHTML += (perc);
            document.getElementById('capitalizzazione').innerHTML += (cap);
            document.getElementById('dataTrade').innerHTML += (date);
            document.getElementById('price').innerHTML += (price);
        }
    });
```

##### To:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nt-5-zruTuJPOAfRbCgy9sJA2CCVvzo0sCPEPx0uxEk/pub?output=csv"
}).done(csv => {
  let [header, ...values] = Papa.parse(csv).data;
  values = values.map(r => r.map(c => {
    const t = c.trim().replace(",", ".");
    return isNaN(t) ? t : Number(t);
  }));
  const obj = values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => Object.assign(o, {[header[j] && header[j].trim()]: c}), {}));
  obj.forEach(data => {
    var perc = data['changepct'];
    var cap = data['marketcap'];
    var date = data['tradetime'];
    var price = data['price'];
    document.getElementById('perc').innerHTML += (perc);
    document.getElementById('capitalizzazione').innerHTML += (cap);
    document.getElementById('dataTrade').innerHTML += (date);
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML += (price);
  });
});
```

- In this modification, please load `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>` for parsing the CSV data to an array.
- I think that the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nt-5-zruTuJPOAfRbCgy9sJA2CCVvzo0sCPEPx0uxEk/pub?output=csv` can be also used instead of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nt-5-zruTuJPOAfRbCgy9sJA2CCVvzo0sCPEPx0uxEk/pub?output=csv`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Thank you, really very kind! Super effective solution!